Vite build problem with tslib.es6.mjs (Uncaught TypeError: R2 is not a function)
I have a React App setup in an npm workspace
/apps
    /fe-app
/common
    /common
    /common-fe

common-fe depends on common
fe-app depends on common-fe
previously I used CRA with babel/webpack to bundle, but recently I switched to vite
commons are not bundled, instead they are used directly as file deps (for which I use tsc -w during development and tsc -b before bundling)
now... everything seems to work when I execute vite (dev build)
but... when I use vite build and then vite preview - the build succeeds and preview runs the browser, which then in turn ruturns the Uncaught TypeError: R2 is not a function
error
note: R2 is pretty consistent across different setups
2nd and 3rd levels of this stacktrace come from the ApolloClient library. maybe connected, but not sure
apollo call
I tried many different tsconfig.json / package.json / vite.config.ts settings. most of them probably even didn't make any sense, but I simply have no idea what's wrong or how to diagnose it. I'd be grateful for any suggestions as to how to approach this problem.
Providing all config files may be too much information, so I'll provide files as requested.
Below I'll list the most important things:
tsconfig

(everywhere) "target": "ES2022"
(everywhere) "module": "ESNext"
(everywhere) "moduleResolution": "Node"
(everywhere) "useDefineForClassFields": true
(everywhere) "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
fe-app paths set to common-fe
common-fe paths set to common

package.json

fe-app has a dep set to common-fe through filesystem
common-fe has a dep set to common through filesystem

vite

fe-app has the following config

plugins: [
        tsconfigPaths(),
        react({ tsDecorators: true })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
            'common-fe': resolve(__dirname, '../../common/common-fe/src'),
            'common': resolve(__dirname, '../../common/common')
        }
    }

I did try to reproduce this with a small example, but as with most of those weird problems... it just works in my example.

I'm not quite sure what the problem was, but the solution for me was to:

remove a library that depended on global and Buffer
remove all usages of vite-plugin-node-polyfills
simplify the build as much as possible

and then it started working
so now my build looks as follows:
  const defaultConfig: UserConfig = {
    plugins: [react()],
    define: envVars,
    server: {
      port: 3003,
    },
    preview: {
      port: 3003,
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
        'common-fe': resolve(__dirname, '../../common/common-fe'),
        'common-fe-src': resolve(__dirname, '../../common/common-fe/src'),
        'common': resolve(__dirname, '../../common/common'),
      },
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
      include: ['common-fe'],
    },
    esbuild: {
      minifyIdentifiers: true,
    },

    build: {
      sourcemap: false,
      minify: 'esbuild',
      chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1200,
      commonjsOptions: { include: [/common-fe/, /node_modules/] }
    }
  };

